# Ionic Login Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Query error. [Extra]: null

Tags: angular, facebook, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I am using the Facebook login in android.
Code:

```
loginFB() {
  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === "connected") {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        console.log("this.isLoggedIn = true");
        this.Erreur = "isLoggedIn = true <br/>";
        console.log(this.users);
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.Erreur = "isLoggedIn = false <br/>";
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e)
      this.Erreur = "Error 1 <br/>" + e.errorMessage + "<br/>";
    });
}
```

but always getting the following error:

```
SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]:null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem was in key hash.

I have discovered that the key hash extracted using Java keytool is different from the one generated by Java code inside my Android app even though I have strictly followed all instructions in Facebook Login Developer page to get the key hash.
I don't' know why they are different, but now after using key hash extracted from java code and pasting it to the project console in Facebook Developer page, my app worked fine..

Comment: How do you extract it?  It's happening to me also.  I'm using a MAC